# When did I run a Docker image?

Tags: docker

I want to know when a specific Docker image has been started. I can look up the image with `docker images`. But the image is not listed by using `docker ps -a` because we run images with the `--rm` option, and therefore, containers will get deleted right after they have ended.

Is there some kind of log which can tell when a specific image has been run?

I tried `docker inspect`, but it doesn’t contain the information I need. Also, `/var/log/docker.log` didn’t help me either.

Comment: I updated my question to make it clearer I've used `docker run --rm`. Therefore the answers from @tgogos, @Rohan and @user2915097 do not yet answer my question because `docker ps` or `docker container inspect` will _not_ list the container created from the image because it doesn’t exist anymore. I just want the info when an image has been started. (I begin to suspect there are no logs about that, but that is the question at hand)

Answer (score 3):

It's better to think of it this way:

1. you don't `run` **images**, but
2. you `run` **containers** based on an **image**.

So, with: `docker container inspect <your_container_name>` you get a lot of information like:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "4b9fdc1aa126c24461bfc1309517c0394da7b67af4b92aaedb5d635deb7d4561",
        "Created": "2017-12-19T12:36:56.038085061Z",
        "Path": "/run.sh",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 5171,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-12-20T11:05:50.753491979Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2017-12-19T16:49:28.78225137Z"
        },
...
```

I believe you look for:

- `Created`: which is when the container was created by running `docker run ...` or
- `StartedAt`: which is when the container was started by running `docker container start ...` (This might have been used if one has `started` a container that was previously `stopped`)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily see STATUS and up-time by using **docker ps** command.

Look for STATUS and CREATED columns.

$ **docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE       COMMAND   CREATED        STATUS         PORTS               NAMES
7ccd6b46a2e9    httpd:2.4   "httpd"   7 minutes ago  Up 7 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp      its-apache
```

Answer (score 0):

the command `docker ps --filter ancestor=xxx` does what you look for

See the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

Example

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
bc07fd1d98a9        k3ck3c/captvty                        "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   5 days ago          Up 50 seconds                                gallant_stallman
2007c8a2344c        k3ck3c/captvty_v3_1                   "/bin/sh -c 'wine ..."   5 days ago          Up 49 seconds                                cranky_wilson
e06b854ce5ad        k3ck3c/captvty                        "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   9 days ago          Up 49 seconds                                quirky_mclean
d24d2a0efafa        phusion/baseimage                     "bash"                   11 days ago         Up 44 seconds                                sad_rosalind
ff00ab6e6113        170d69d7c3c8                          "/bin/sh -c 'apt-g..."   11 days ago         Up 43 seconds                                competent_ramanujan
6801d8ad513a        596df975d7c3                          "/bin/sh -c 'dpkg ..."   2 weeks ago         Up 39 seconds                                loving_nobel
46994fddc6ba        solarkennedy/wine-x11-novnc-docker    "/usr/bin/supervisord"   2 weeks ago         Up 36 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   naughty_shannon
2070187bf6d2        k3ck3c/captvty                        "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 36 seconds                                vibrant_agnesi
b151e3654bab        k3ck3c/captvty_v3_1                   "/bin/sh -c 'wine ..."   2 weeks ago         Up 35 seconds                                stupefied_brahmagupta
37e30ba9c5cf        k3ck3c/captvty                        "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 35 seconds                                naughty_boyd
d5f57a41bd0b        k3ck3c/captvty                        "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 34 seconds                                musing_mahavira
3a10baa66e99        ac68b5fd0b98                          "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 34 seconds                                elegant_thompson
5db88185bf4c        71d3f94833a9                          "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   3 weeks ago         Up 33 seconds                                vigilant_saha
11b4606ccad2        k3ck3c/apt_cacher                     "/bin/sh -c 'chmod..."   6 weeks ago         Up 31 seconds       0.0.0.0:3142->3142/tcp   test_apt_cacher_ng
2da4d5c73b21        monitoringartist/grafana-xxl:latest   "/run.sh"                9 months ago        Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   grafana-xxl2
```

If I want only the containers running the image k3ck3c/apt_cacher

```
$ docker ps --filter ancestor=k3ck3c/apt_cacher
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
11b4606ccad2        k3ck3c/apt_cacher   "/bin/sh -c 'chmod..."   6 weeks ago         Up 58 seconds       0.0.0.0:3142->3142/tcp   test_apt_cacher_ng
$
```

or the image `k3ck3c/captvty`

```
$ docker ps --filter ancestor=k3ck3c/captvty
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bc07fd1d98a9        k3ck3c/captvty      "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   5 days ago          Up 5 minutes                            gallant_stallman
e06b854ce5ad        k3ck3c/captvty      "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   9 days ago          Up 5 minutes                            quirky_mclean
2070187bf6d2        k3ck3c/captvty      "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 4 minutes                            vibrant_agnesi
37e30ba9c5cf        k3ck3c/captvty      "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 4 minutes                            naughty_boyd
d5f57a41bd0b        k3ck3c/captvty      "/bin/sh -c 'WINED..."   2 weeks ago         Up 4 minutes                            musing_mahavira
$
```